# Feasible set for linear system with linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have a linear *underdetermined* system $Ax = b$ with constraints $0 \le x \le 1$. Matrix $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times m}$ with $n < m$, elements of which are either $0$ or $1$, and sum of each column equals to $2$.

Is there any *analytical* way to check if there is a solution at all? If yes, how can we get any of the solutions from the feasible set?

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you need the solution to be analytical? Do you intend only to perform these computations on paper? :-)

Comment: I want to run solver only if there is a solution.

Comment: OK, but why? For speed reasons? I mean, it may actually be possible to determine infeasibility slightly faster than finding a solution. But it will be basically the same algorithm.

Comment: I want to get insights about cases when the solution can be found.